# Infinitely elongated windows in python 3.6.1, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a medical calculator which has various kinds of equations.
This has a small menu and user can convert from one to another. 
But when i tested this, I had found out that the GUI windows getting longer and longer without destroying pre-created F frame.. :(

I don't know what it happened. Could you explain this problem?
Thanks.

This is abbreviated codes.

```
import tkinter
import math
top = Tk()
F = Frame(top, width = 512, height = 512)
F.pack()

def temp():
   print("This is temporary function")

def fena():
   F.destroy()
   making_fena()

def making_fena:
   F= Frame(top)
   F.pack()
   .....
   #every widgets are attached to this F frame by grid.
   ....

def bsa():
   F.destroy()
   making_bsa()

def making_bsa():
   F.destroy()
   F = Frame(top)
   F.pack()
   ....
   #every widgets are attached to this F frame by grid.
   ...

#Making a menu 
#Basic menu 1: Calc - FeNa - GFR - BSA 
#Basic Menu 2: Quit
menubar = Menu(top)
calcmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
calcmenu.add_command(label = "FeNa", command = fena)
calcmenu.add_command(label = "GFR", command = temp)
calcmenu.add_command(label = "BSA", command = bsa)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "Calc", menu = calcmenu)

menubar.add_command(label = "Quit", command = top.quit)

top.config(menu = menubar)

#loop running
top.mainloop()
```

I intentionally used a same frame name (F) for every equation. I thought that it will not make any errors when I across from one equation to another. Is this my critical mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at one of your functions for an example...

```
def making_fena:
   F= Frame(top)
   F.pack()
```

This function contains an assignment to `F`, and no global declaration of `F`, therefore `F` is a *local variable* in this function - entirely unrelated to your global `F` variable.  Every time you destroy and recreate `F`, you're actually re-destroying the original global `F`, and adding a brand new local `F` to your window.  Thus, the infinitely growth.  You need to add `global F` to each function like this.